# Dynamic cell, static addition

Tags: excel, ms-office, office365

Ok, so I think I'm looking to do a dynamic cell, but not sure on the correct wording.

Essentially what I'm looking to do is have a cell, say A1, A2, A3 and A4 that all show nothing by themselves, but have a formula that would be something like this:

```
=SUM(ENTEREDVALUE+4.95)
```

Really I'm just looking to have 4 cells (think of it weekly since it's for a budget setup) that show nothing by default, but if I put `77.50` into the cell, it automatically adds `4.95` to what I entered.

I know some hackish ways to do it, but nothing like what I'm looking to do, if it's even possible.

Comment: It means for my needs I can "hack" (no, I didn't mean it as "it's a hack job, as it's a legit formula obviously) it together by putting 4.95 in A1,  the user-entered value in B1 and then the result in C1 but I don't want to have to always do =SUM(A1+B1) in C1, since I might want to pay it in C2 in a given month.

I'm just looking for a way to add 4.95 (a static number) to a cell if and when I enter an number in said cell.

So technically something like (I know not a real formula, but using words for what I mean)  - IF"uservalue"HASDATA=SUM(uservalue+4.95)

Comment: I only have Unicode Text and Text under Paste Special?

Comment: Really, I'm almost looking to "format" the cell to just add a static value to any entered number...

Comment: I see your point, but at the end of the day, as much as I'm looking to strictly save time, I'd just as easily remember "Hey, you know this bill charges $4.95 to pay online". You know? :(

Comment: Right, I can copy two values and do paste special, operation add but what are you looking for me to do with it? Copy the value in A1 and the static value in B1 and just paste them?

Comment: I mean it works, but it's just one and the same with how I meant I can always write the formula. This just makes it so I copy/paste it. There's no real way to have a cell do "if data is entered into this cell, add 4.95" I guess. Oh well.